# tflite_flutter & tflite_flutter_helper - how to convert image to greyscale with one channel?

Tags: flutter, image-processing, tflite

I'm trying to run a tflite model in flutter, and this model requires greyscale 48x48 images, so I'm trying to convert the TensorImage to have the input shape of (48, 48, 1), but I'm unable to. Even if I use something like [Image.grayscale](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/grayscale.html), the shape stays as (48, 48, 3), so how do I convert it to (48, 48, 1), i.e. make the image have only one channel.

Code:

```
    final interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('model.tflite');

    final inputShape = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape;
    final inputType = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).type;
    final outputShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape;
    final outputType = interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).type;
    
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/1');
    img.Image dataImg = img.decodeImage(data.buffer.asUint8List())!;
    
    TensorImage tensorImage = TensorImage(inputType);
    tensorImage.loadImage(dataImg);
```